# jquery to find the closest div with multiple divs having the same class name

Tags: jquery

How can I find the closest available div with multiple divs having the same id/class name on the page?

Example:

```
<div1 class='comment-1'>...</div>
<div2 class='comment-1'>...</div>
<div3 class='comment-1'>...</div>
<div4 class='comment-1'>...</div>
<div5 class='comment-1'>...</div>
```

Comment: ids must be **unique**

Comment: you don't. That syntax is invalid and it's not guaranteed that the js works. Or you can change the example using class instead of id. ;)

Comment: `How can I find the closest...` closest to what?

Comment: Besides, your HTML elements are `div1`, `div2`..., not `div`.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant div with the same class, you can take a look at the [jQuery 'closest' method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: yes, this worked.. actually I had to find a particular anchor tag in each of the divs with same classnames.. thanks!  $(id-name).closest('div.classname').find('a.classname');